# Loading an image file in WP 8 application from directory

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, loading-image

i am developing a WP 8 application and i want to load an image which is currently on my computer drive. Here is my Code

```
  try
        {
            using (FileStream fileStream = File.OpenRead("\\TiltFilter\\FilterEffects\\Assets\\AlignmentGrid.png")) 
            {
                MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
                memStream.SetLength(fileStream.Length);
                fileStream.Read(memStream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)fileStream.Length);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string str = e.Message;
        }
```

It gives me exception that of Type

> System.Io.DirectoryNotFoundexception`and the message is`Could not
>   find a part of the path
>   'C:\TiltFilter\FilterEffects\Assets\AlignmentGrid.png'.

Can some body help me that how i can load the image in memorystream on WP8

Thanks

Comment: Yes that's right. So how i can load the image from my Assets folder in WP 8 application

Comment: I'd suggest the same that Paul has suggested below. You could even make it part of the project's content files so that it automatically gets copied every time you deploy the application. If this is a one time operation, manual copying may be far faster.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add an image to your project as `Content` and use `GetResourceStream` to access a stream of an image:

```
var resource = App.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Assets/AlignmentGrid.png", UriKind.Relative));
var buffer = new byte[resource.Stream.Length];
resource.Stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

Comment: Also change the properties of the image in Vs studio to Content. And also set the property of "Copy to OutPut directory" to   "Copy if newer".

Comment: Thanks!  This helped me out trying to copy a local text file in the application load to a MemoryStream.  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(); resource.Stream.CopyTo(ms);  I kept getting hung up because I wasn't setting the text file property to "Content" before building.

Answer (score 0):

The phone doesn't understand UNC network paths - it doesn't support the SMB protocol which Windows File Servers use.

You will either need to package up the file so that it is part of the application package (.xap file) and is local to the phone or serve up the assets using a Web Server (i.e. using the http:// protocol).

The first option is obviously the most robust as it doesn't require that the phone has a network connection to your server.

For an example of how to do this, see [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2010/09/16/content-or-resource-files-another-way-to-load-a-static-xml-file-to-your-application.aspx) for the difference between packaging "Content" and "Resource" files (it mentions XML files, but the concepts are the same for any file type).

Answer (score 0):

A Windows phone app can only access the it's own [**Isolated Storage**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), and the SD Card

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402541%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

If you want to share files between Pc and Phone you can use a webservice.