# Saving image file to isolated storage

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, isolatedstorage

I am creating a Windows Phone 8 application. I have an image which is currently on my computer disk. I want to store that image in my isolated storage. The problem i am facing is that, that how i will load the image in my application so that i will store the image data in my isolated storage.

The problem is that, the image is located on my computer disk and when i attach the device and run the application it will try to find the file in local sandbox and hence i will get the exception.

> System.Io.DirectoryNotFound

Any help will be great.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loading an image file in WP 8 application from directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17292041/loading-an-image-file-in-wp-8-application-from-directory)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to upload files from your computer to the isolated storage of your app?

I haven't tried it myself but you might want to take a look at [Windows Phone Power Tools.](https://wptools.codeplex.com/) According to their own site they let you "Upload / Download Files from IsolatedStorage".

Another option might be [ISE (Isolated Storage Explorer)](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c4cdb312-2017-4370-a572-8c38526f4b4a).

If you want to access your files on your computer at runtime, I do not believe this is possible.